# Configuration file parser with a range of servers

Tags: php, string, parsing

I have difficulties with the parser, I ask for help with advice

I have a configuration file in which the servers are listed in different sections in this format

```
[section1]
kt1.domen.local
p01.domen.local
 
 
[section2]
av1.domen.local
s03.domen.local
s[01:19].domen.local
s[34:59].domen.local
```

The file is parsed normally and I upload the values I need, but only in cases when I do not rest on the record of a range of servers of type s[34:59].domen.local

that is, I need to do a check and if there
is a conditional [NUMBER] in the string:NUMBER].domen.local
string to convert to strings listing each server in the specified range

The place where I get this line

```
{
  $s_tmp=trim($s_tmp);
  //echo $s_tmp."<br />";
}
```

I start parsing through regular expressions like this

```
{
  $s_tmp=trim($s_tmp);
 
  if ( preg_match("/\[([0-9:]+)([0-9]+).+\]/",$s_tmp, $matches ) )
  {
    echo $matches[0]."<br />";
  }
  else
  {
    echo $s_tmp."<br />";
  }
}
```

preg_match ( "/[([0-9:]+)([0-9]+).+]/" ... ... finds the necessary strings, but I can't figure out how to convert them to a range line by line

Answer (score 1):

You convert the parsed numbers into int values, iterate over the interval using a loop, then you can simply concatenate the tokens to form the server names:

```
<?php
$input = "s[01:19].domen.local";
$output = [];
 
if (preg_match("/^(\w+)\[(\d+):(\d+)]([\w\d.]+)$/", $input, $matches)) {
    for ($i=(int)$matches[2]; $i<=(int)$matches[3]; $i++) {
        $output[] = sprintf('%s%02d%s', $matches[1], $i, $matches[4]);
    }
}

print_r($output);
```

The output of above implementation is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => s01.domen.local
    [1] => s02.domen.local
    [2] => s03.domen.local
    [3] => s04.domen.local
    [4] => s05.domen.local
    [5] => s06.domen.local
    [6] => s07.domen.local
    [7] => s08.domen.local
    [8] => s09.domen.local
    [9] => s10.domen.local
    [10] => s11.domen.local
    [11] => s12.domen.local
    [12] => s13.domen.local
    [13] => s14.domen.local
    [14] => s15.domen.local
    [15] => s16.domen.local
    [16] => s17.domen.local
    [17] => s18.domen.local
    [18] => s19.domen.local
)
```

This obviously assumes that the numbers are always two characters wide.